# How to create a java object corresponding to the composite key including relation in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to Java, I will explain my problem as this.

As per my knowledge, in the relational database, if there any relationship between two tables, we are keeping a reference through a foreign key. As follows. The **Employee** and **Company** tables have a relationship. **Employee** table keeping a relationship with the **Company** by referring to the companyId as the foreign key. that is about relational database.

[image]

In java programming, we can create corresponding objects to the above-mentioned tables named **Employee** and **Company** as follows.

```
class Company{
    private int companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private String address;

    //getters and setters
}

class Employee{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int companyId;//this field use to refer the company table

    //getters and setters
}
```

In Employee class **companyId** used to refer the Company class.

When have multi values in a relational tables, For example, we get two tables like **Student** and **Subject**. student can have many subject, as well as subject, can belong to the many student. In this occasion, we need to create another table named **Student_Subject** by using a composite key according to the first normal form. composite key(studentId, subjectId) can use to refer uniquely the subjects belongs to a particular student.

My question is this table(**Student_Subject**) how to represent java application as in the above example. Are we create a new class corresponding to the  **Student_Subject** as follows

```
class StudentSubject{
     private int subjectId;
     private int studentId;

     //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious method is to put a collection of subject IDs in your `Student` class:

```
class Student {
    int id;
    String name;
    ...
    Set<Integer> subjectIds = new HashSet<>();
}
```

If needed, you can also add a list of student IDs in your `Subject` class.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is many-to-many associations between Student and Subject Entity.

Please check https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/ for the example.

**Also you can do it without StudentSubject entity if you using the simple id's of the tables**. just by using @JoinTable mapping which will store the relationship.

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

The above one is plain object , we can do like that , if you are looking for JPA way in Java no need one extra table **Student_Subject** class, below is the example for JPA way below is reference

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html